# How to display dynamically generated elements with slideDown()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I use the following code to change the content of `.elements` when `#select-element` value is changed:

```
$("#select-element").on('change', function () {
  var dtype = $("#select-element").val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/?type='+dtype,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      for (var r in result) {
        var row = ' \
          <div class="row">result[r].name \
          </div> \
        ';
        $('.elements').prepend(row);
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
      $(".elements").slideUp(function() {
        $(".elements").children().remove();
      });
    },
    complete: function(){
      $(".elements").slideDown();
    }
  });
});
```

It works well if I remove `slideUp()` functions. But if it is there, then new content is not displayed. Looks like the problem is with `slideDown()` function, which doesn't want to display dynamically generated element.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You may have a race condition between the slideUp callback and the completion of the ajax request

Comment: Check if `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` works. If it does not then i don't think the problem is not `slideDown`. If fade in and out works then you may try doing it with css transitions. with overflow:hidden and height:0 for slideUp, and e.g. height:200px; for slideDown.

Comment: @Roy, `fadeIn` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the slideUp() duration is 400ms by default. Then after that 400ms has elapsed you remove the children.

Suppose the ajax is done in 200ms (less time than animation duration)... your new content will already be inserted at the time the `children().remove()` gets called.

I suggest you remove the `beforeSend` and `complete` and combine everything into the `slideUp` callback inside `success` handler.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '/?type=' + dtype,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(result) {
     var $elems = $(".elements");
     // do slideUp
     $elems.slideUp(function() {
       // now change content
       $elems.empty();

       for (var r in result) {
         var row = ' \
          <div class="row">result[r].name \
          </div> \
        ';
         $elems.prepend(row);
       }
       // and display new content
       $elems.slideDown();
     });
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {}
 });
```

An alternative would be to use promise returned by jQuery animations

Comment: Can you provide some tutorial/article to work with Promise in jQuery? I did it in Angular but still pretty unclear about how it works.